# Differentiate between youTube URLs and the file names of embedded MP4s?

Tags: javascript, html, url, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I want to, in my init() function, check to see if the video is either a youtube URL or a file name.

Does this seem suitable or is there some kind of edge case I might be missing?

```
    function init(){
        playerSource = Document.getElementById('vid').src;
        if ( playerSource.includes("https://www.youtube") ){
            //Call to function that begins setting up YT iFrame API
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the youtube URL using below regex.

```
regExp = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/
```

Youtube has different url forms depending upon where you are taking from

Normal Url

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678901
```

Share Url

```
https://youtu.be/12345678901
```

Share Url with start time

```
https://youtu.be/12345678901?t=6
```

Mobile browser url

```
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678901&list=RD12345678901&start_radio=1
```

Long url

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678901&list=RD12345678901&start_radio=1&rv=smKgVuS
```

Long url with start time

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678901&list=RD12345678901&start_radio=1&rv=12345678901&t=38
```

You can check these URL validation below
https://regex101.com/r/7a1lGH/1

Comment: Regex never occurred to me but it seems obvious now that you've laid it out! Thanks a lot for taking the time :)